# Applying Operations on each element of the list

Tags: netlogo

I wish to divide each element in a list by a number, I have tried the following:

Approach 1:

```
set item 0 (new-vec item 0 vec / number)
set item 1 (new-vec item 1 vec / number)
```

gives error this isn't something you can use set on

Approach 2:

```
 foreach new-vec
[ set ? ? / number]
```

doesn't seem to work.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [NetLogo lists](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#lists) are immutable data structures.

If you really want mutability you can always use the [array extension](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/arraystables.html), but once you've learned to use NetLogo's immutable lists properly, this is almost never necessary: the [lists primitives](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#listsgroup) are usually all that you need.

To divide all the numbers in a list by some other number, use [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map):

```
let new-vec [10 50 100]
let number 10
let divided-vec map [ ? / number ] new-vec
```

will assign the list `[1 5 10]` to `divided-vec`.

The [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) operation builds a new list by applying an operation to each element of the list you pass to it. In the example above, I assigned the new list to a new variable (`divided-vec`), but if you wanted, you could also assign it back to `new-vec`:

```
set new-vec map [ ? / number ] new-vec
```

This will behave as if you modified `new-vec` in place, though it won't be the case.

If you want to apply an operation to just one item in a list, you can do it with a combination of [`replace-item`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#replace-item) and [`item`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#item):

```
let my-list [2 4 6 8 10]
show replace-item 1 my-list (item 1 my-list  * 100)
```

will show: `[2 400 6 8 10]`

Comment: How can I use replace-item command with out using show in front of it. 
In general my question is, How can we apply any operation to one item of list. I tried to use replace item it but its is giving error.

Comment: `replace-item` is a reporter that returns a modified copy of the list. I used `show` to print that list in the command center, but you can do whatever you want with it: store it in a variable, pass it a an argument to another procedure, etc. As for your other question, I would suggest you ask that as an official question; comments are not a good place for question and answers.

Comment: I got an error says "nothing named ? has been defined" when I use the map approach. Anybody has idea why is it like this? Many thanks!

Comment: You need to convert the code to NetLogo 6 syntax: use something like `map [ n -> n / number ] new-vec` instead of `map [ ? / number ] new-vec`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it in NetLogo 6, which changed anonymous procedures and thus how this is done in [map](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map):

```
let new-vec [10 50 100]
let number 10
let divided-vec map [ i -> i / number ] new-vec
```